# How to redirect any links valid or invalid in my website to the index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website its domain name is : http://cabinets.ga

- My website is a single page application using ajax to do all of its requests.
- I want for example if the user writes on the browser http://cabinets.ga/login/login.php or any other link (directory or file, exists or not exists) the .htaccess redirect it to the index.php because i want that all of my requests in my website will only be with jquery ajax.
- This is my Code but it doesn't work exactly:

  ```
  Options 
  +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  ```

*Any update on my code or any other code or way to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Create page 404.php**
in that page just redirect to your index.php

using php

```
header("Location: index.php")
```

Comment: _Vicky: cabinets.ga redirected you too many times, i got this error

Answer (score 1):

To redirect all requests to `/index.php` you can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule !index\.php /index.php [L,R]
```